# Android apps, communicating with a device via USB port

Tags: android, device-driver, linux-device-driver

I am new to Android Platform and I Like to know whether it is possile for an Android device(App) to communicate with  Linux system via USB port for 2 way communication . If yes how it can be done . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB support is limited in Android currently and only available on > 3.0. Look at the online developer's docs.

[USB Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html)